# How to get a question reopened?

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-reopen

A [specific question](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/481515) has been closed because of previous answers to the question. I disagreed and voted to re-open because the question was specific and there was a specific answer whereas the quoted answers did not address the specifics.

How can I contact/persuade the no voters to re-open the question? I have added a comment about this after the question but will anyone see it?

Comment: Please add a link to the question. We can vote to reopen.

Comment: @CarLaTeX -- here you are: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/481515

Comment: @barbarabeeton Voted to reopen, thanks!

Comment: The question is reopened now!

Comment: @user49915 there was a small typo in the url (`text` instead of `tex`), I've corrected it.

Answer (score 6):

The usual approach is to vote to reopen (if you have that [privilege](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions)). It's reasonable to add a comment suggesting why you want to reopen the post as other users who review it won't know what may have changed since the post has been closed.

If that fails, visit the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) where there are heavy-weights that could be persuaded to support you (including [moderators](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators)).

If chatting is not your thing, posting to [TeX.Meta.SE](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com) (as you did) is another option as it would get broader attention to a specific post.

Answer (score 2):

You voted to reopen the question. After that, all users with 3000 reputations or more would see the question in the "Reopen Votes" review queue. They would go to read the question, read your comment and have their decisions. That is the only way you can "contact" all other eligible users to persuade them to reopen, as far as I know.

However, you can express your opinion and persuade many users (not all users) via [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41). But your messages are never private.